# How do you create an SQLite Database with c# in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, android, database, sqlite, xamarin

I am creating an `SQLite` Database in `Visual Studio` with `Xamarin` in `C#`.

I should note that this is for `android` only.

From what I understand, in this class I must create the `SQLite` Database, and make it so I am able to add, delete, and retrieve data.

I should also note that there is a separate class to call the methods in this class.

I am very new to this and I am not sure how to do this.

I've read tutorials, I've watched hour long videos, and I still am not able to figure out this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the class template I am using and must follow:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

using BB.Mobile.Models;

namespace BB.Mobile
{
    /// <summary>
/// A class to provide a single interface for interacting with all SQLite data operations for stored tracking points.
/// </summary>
class DataManager
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Will compile and return all matching unsynchronized ping data from the SQLite database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<PingGroup> GetUnsynchronizedPings()
    {
        List<PingGroup> unsynchronizedPings = new List<PingGroup>();

        // TODO: Retrieve all unsynchronized pings from the SQLite database and return them to the caller.

        return unsynchronizedPings;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Insert a single ping group into the SQLite ping database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pingGroup"></param>
    public void AddUnsynchronizedPing(PingGroup pingGroup)
    {
        // TODO: Add the passed ping group parameter into the SQLite database as new/unsynchronized.


    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Mark all open and unsynchronized pings in the database as synchronized.
    /// </summary>
    public void SetAllPingsSynchronized()
    {
        // TODO: Delete all database data or set it as synchronized using a flag.

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Did you read this? http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2014/10/database-first-with-sqlite-in-universal.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SQLite Component](https://components.xamarin.com/view/sqlite-net) has pretty clear documentation - is there something specific you don't understand?

```
using SQLite;
// ...

public class Note
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

// Create our connection
string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
var db = new SQLiteConnection (System.IO.Path.Combine (folder, "notes.db"));
db.CreateTable<Note>();

// Insert note into the database
var note = new Note { Message = "Test Note" };
db.Insert (note);
```

Comment: Hi. I just want to ask, if we can keep any extension of the created file or it must have to be fileName.db (i.e. .db). Thanks in advance

Comment: I don’t believe the extension matters